# How to validate array to be sure all of them are not empty

Tags: node.js, express, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to validate Array of object using express validator, this object has 2 attributes  and both of them should be integer i couldn't reach anything to that array

request body

```
{"x":[{"foo":2,"bar":10},{"foo":2,"bar":10},{"foo":3,"bar":9}]}
```

how could i validate them  foo and bar? i can validate attribute when  it is a single object like this request body `{"foo":"10","bar":"10"}`
i validate them with this schema

```
  foo: {
    in: 'body',
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid value',
  },
  bar: {
    in: 'body',
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid value',
  },
  },
```

and then i put this code in order to validate the request

```
Validation.validate(req.body, this.schema)
```

Please advise

Comment: express-validator seems not to be a [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) compliant validator. The standard gives you an easy, reusable and programming-language independent way to describe your JSON data. For Javascript, take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Comment: yes it's separated java script file  i put it like this 


` module.exports = {foo: {
    in: 'body',
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid value',
  },
  bar: {
    in: 'body',
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid value',
  },
  }, `